# How to display custom post meta box data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using custom meta boxes for the first time and I am having trouble figuring out and understanding how to display the data in the box. I the box show up in posts and it saves the data, but I don't know how to display it. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

The functions.php code for creating the custom meta box:

```
    function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");

    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="meta-box-checkbox">Display CTA Area?</label>
            <?php
                $checkbox_value = get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-checkbox", true);

                if($checkbox_value == "")
                {
                    ?>
                        <input name="meta-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true">
                    <?php
                }
                else if($checkbox_value == "true")
                {
                    ?>  
                        <input name="meta-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" checked>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            <br>

            <label for="meta-box-text">Call to Action Title</label>
            <input name="meta-box-text" type="text" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-text", true); ?>">

            <br>

            <label for="meta-box-button">CTA Button Text</label>
            <input name="meta-box-button" type="text" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-button", true); ?>">

        </div>
    <?php  
}

function add_custom_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Custom Meta Box", "custom_meta_box_markup", "post", "normal", "high", null);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");

function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $slug = "post";
    if($slug != $post->post_type)
        return $post_id;

    $meta_box_text_value = "";
    $meta_box_checkbox_value = "";
    $meta_box_button_value = "";

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-text"]))
    {
        $meta_box_text_value = $_POST["meta-box-text"];
    }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-text", $meta_box_text_value);

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-button"]))
    {
        $meta_box_text_value = $_POST["meta-box-button"];
    }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-button", $meta_box_text_value);

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-checkbox"]))
    {
        $meta_box_checkbox_value = $_POST["meta-box-checkbox"];
    }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-checkbox", $meta_box_checkbox_value);
}

add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);
```

And this is how I am trying to get the data displayed in a template:

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1><!--display "meta-box-text"--></h1>
    <button><!--display "meta-box-button"--></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-text",true); inside of your post loop